# Justificar Texto em Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

Tenho uma aplicação que o texto é exibido em um textBlock e quero fazer com que esse texto fique justificado, ja tentei colocar o alinhamento do texto como justificado, porém não foi, diz que o método não é suportado.

Ja me responderam antes com o link deste artigo ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.95).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4 ), porem não deu certo.

Existe algum outro componente para Windows Phone que aceite texto justificado, se alguem souber me ajudar ficarei muito grato, estou precisando conserta isso no meu app ;´(.

Muito Obrigado desde de já.
Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho muito conhecimento de `xaml`, mas conforme está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11567907/1518921)

Você pode usar um `RichTextBox` para conseguir o efeito desejado:

```
<RichTextBox TextAlignment="Justify" IsReadOnly="True">
    <Paragraph>
        Coloque o seu texto aqui
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Note que em aplicações Desktop o problema parece não ocorrer com o `TextBox`

```
<TextBlock Text="Coloque o seu texto aqui"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           TextAlignment="Justify"></TextBlock>
```